# jQuery not firing on load/ready when server responce is slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I fire a function on jQuery(document).ready() and on jQuery(window).load(). Both the same function. It is supposed to fire an image resize script.

However, sometimes, when the server is slow to respond, the script doesn't fire at all when the page is done loading.

I've been having this problem for quite a while now, and, maybe it's overkill, but by now, I call the function as shown below, in both the document ready and the window load:

```
    jQuery('img', '.background').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).load(function(){
            jQuery(this).resizeImage();
        });
    });
```

The function it calls is:

```
jQuery.fn.resizeImage = function() {
console.log('fired');
var bgImg = jQuery(this);

/* get img sizes */
var imgwidth = bgImg.width();
var imgheight = bgImg.height();

/* get window sizes */
var winwidth = jQuery(window).width();
var winheight = jQuery(window).height();
/* get the ratio, checks wether window is bigger or smaller than the image */
var widthratio = winwidth / imgwidth;
var heightratio = winheight / imgheight;
/* checks the difference */
var widthdiff = heightratio * imgwidth;
var heightdiff = widthratio * imgheight;
/* if you want the entire image to always fit the screen, change the > to < */
if(heightdiff>winheight) { 
    bgImg.css({
        width: winwidth+'px',
        height: heightdiff+'px',
        marginLeft: '-'+winwidth/2+'px'
    });
} else {
    bgImg.css({
        width: widthdiff+'px',
        height: winheight+'px',
        marginLeft: '-'+widthdiff/2+'px'
    });     
}
};
```

Using the console.log, I found that the function doesn't fire at all.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this might not work?

Comment: Keep the scripts at the bottom of the page. Just above `</body>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself.

The issue was in the following:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    jQuery('img', '.background').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).load(function(){
            jQuery(this).resizeImage();
        });
    });
});
```

Due to the double load (jQuery(window).load and jQuery(this).load) the code didn't execute at all. Since when the window is loaded, the images are already loaded as well.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you're miss using the `this`

```
   jQuery('img', '.background').each(function(){
        var $self = $(this);
        $self.load(function(){
            $self.resizeImage();
        });
    });
```

Comment: I tried that, but then the code doesn't work anymore at all. I don't really see why it would make a difference though, since the only difference is that you store jQuery(this) in a variable, where I just use it straight away.